# MVC RedirectToAction and custom filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

My Action have some custom Filter

```
    [CustomFilters.LibrarianAction]
    [CustomFilters.LibraryUserAction]
    public ActionResult Users()
    {
     // my action code
     ... 

    }
```

when i use

```
    @Html.ActionLink("users")
```

i can get custom filters from this method on OnActionExecuting :

```
    method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomFilters.LibrarianAction), true)
```

but when i use

```
    RedirectToAction("users");
```

the action dose not return any Filter with code :

```
    method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomFilters.LibrarianAction), true)
```

any help?

Comment: Where is the code you are showing implemented? Is it in a custom action filter or in the controller? Where is the `method` variable coming from on which you are calling the `GetCustomAttributes` method? Also could you show where and how you are calling the `RedirectToAction` method?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was from my code to compare names of action.
i didn't use to lower() for compare to string.